# How to search in a map/multimap starting from specific position

Tags: c++, dictionary, search, stl, binary-search

I want to search in a *map/multimap* but not all of it. Instead I want to start in a specific position.

In the following example I want to find the two first numbers that sum *b*. And return their value.

```
multimap<int, int> a;
a.insert(make_pair(2, 0));
a.insert(make_pair(2, 1));
a.insert(make_pair(5, 2));
a.insert(make_pair(8, 3));

int b = 4;

for(auto it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it) {
    auto it2 = a.find(b - it->first); //Is there an equivalent that starts from "it+1"?
    if(it2 != a.end()) {
        cout << it->second << ", " << it2->second << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

output:

```
0, 0
```

desired output:

```
0, 1
```

Is it possible to achieve specific position search in a map?

Comment: `std::map::find()` doesn't "search the entire container". If it did, it's complexity would be `O(n)`. But it's not. As far as the algorithms go, `std::find_if()`, with an appropriate predicate can easily deal with the map's `std::pair`. In conclusion: check your assumptions, and explain what the real problem. No, not the one that's stated, but the one whose solution involves searching a map this way.

Comment: As Sam has said, your question is based on some false assumptions. It might be better to [edit] your question to include the real problem you're trying to solve, including a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have added an example of what I was trying to do. It is ok if it is not possible or I'm using the wrong container, I just wanted to know if I'm missing a way to do it.

Comment: If you what "find the two first numbers that sum b" then it makes no sense to use a map for this. This is not what a map is for. You're trying to use something for something else it's not designed for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to search in a map starting from specific position

You *could* use `std::find`. But this is not ideal, since it has linear complexity compared to logarithmic complexity of a map lookup. The interface of `std::map` doesn't support such operation for lookups.

If you need such operation, then you need to use another data structure. It should be possible to implement by augmenting a (balanced) search tree with a parent node pointer. The downside is of course increased memory use and constant overhead on operations that modify the tree structure.

> not from the beginning to the end.

Map look ups do not start from "the beginning" of the range. They start from the root of the tree.

Comment: How about some stl algorithm like find_if or binary_search?

Comment: @asantacreu You can only use `binary_search` with random access iterators. Map iterators are not random access. You *can* use `find_if` sure. But do realise that it has linear complexity compared to logarithmic complexity of a map lookup.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an ordered map (which it sounds like you are), then it already does binary search with `std::find`. This function returns an iterator type, so assuming you were looking for the value of some key x, then consider the following lines:

```
std::map<char,int> mymap;
mymap['x'] = 24;
std::map<char,int>::iterator itr = mymap.find('x');
std::cout << "x=" << itr->second << std::endl;
```

The reason your code wasn't compiling was likely because you tried to return a pair iterator, which won't exactly print to output all that well. Instead, calling `itr->second` allows you to retrieve the value associated with the desired key.